# I must replace some special characters on Code by Zapier

Tags: javascript, node.js, zapier

I need to replace some special characters on Zapier.

Since there are many substitutions, I want to do it through Code by Zapier.

I made the code, but I got the following error on `Code by Zapier`:

We had trouble sending your test through.
`TypeError: str.replace is not a function`

Here is the code:

```
str = inputData;

str.replace(/Á|Ä|À|Ã|Â/g, "A");
str.replace(/É|Ë|È|Ê/g, "E");
str.replace(/Í|Ï|Ì|Î/g, "I");
str.replace(/Ó|Ö|Ò|Õ|Ô/g, "O");
str.replace(/Ú|Ü|Ù|Û/g, "U");

output = [{outputData: str}];
```

I don't know why str.replace doesn't work on Code by Zapier. I tried use `str = str.replace()`, instead `str.replace()`, but it did not worked too.

Can someone help?

Comment: `inputData` may not be a string. What is the result of `console.log(inputData);`?

Comment: Hi Gary, you are wright! `inputData` is an object and not string. I switched for `inputData.str` and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `inputData` is not a string but rather an object. So if you provided a field to the Code then you need to access it as a property of that object. Let's say the name of the variable is `foo`, then you need to access it as `inputData.foo.replace()` (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: You are right! Thanks for that! 

I corrected it! Now the code runs without any error! 

Thank you very much!